# Is there a way to backup data + user defined enum in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, enums, backup, restore

Is there a way to backup and restore schema + data + user defined enums in postgresql?

I use pgAdmin which uses pg_dump and pg_restore, i select pre data, data, post data to back up, i also select all tables. But when i restore again in an empty database with pgAdmin i get error saying the user defined enums not find. In fact the user defined enums are originally used as column types for some of my tables

Comment: what did you try and what's the problem so far ?

Comment: I use pgAdmin which uses pg_dump and pg_restore, i select pre data, data, post data to back up, i also select all tables. But when i restore again in an empty database with pgAdmin i get error saying the user defined enums not find. In fact the user defined enums are originally used as column types for some of my tables

Answer (score -1):

[pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgdump.html) and [pg_restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgrestore.html) should be adequate.

Comment: Which options you use with pg_dump and ph_restore to backup and restore user defined enums as the default parameters don't do that?

Comment: If you are using them with default (lack of) options from the command line, they should pick up your types, including enums. If they aren't, then I am at a loss and would refer you to Postgres message boards to put together a bug report.